# GOTO in IF Statement Batch Scipt

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, goto

My batch script compares a username to a list of usernames and if the username variable is in the list of usernames, then start `notepad.exe`. Else, print no. I am doing this using GOTO.

So if the username is in the list, goto `match1` and launch notepad. Else, goto `match2` and print no. But it seems even when the username is in the list, it always goes to the else part and prints no. Here's my code:-

```
@ECHO OFF

set user=username1
set list=username3 username2 username1 

(FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (if %user%==%%a (GOTO MATCH1 
) else ( GOTO MATCH2 
)                   
))

:MATCH1
notepad.exe

:MATCH2
echo no 

pause
```

However, when I make the list this way, it launches notepad and prints no:-

```
 set list=username1 username2 username3
```

Please note that when I did this without using GOTO, it worked well. So for example, if there's a match, launch notepad, else, print no. Am I using GOTO in a wrong manner? Or did I misunderstood the functionality of GOTO?

Comment: Try adding a `ECHO %%a` in your loop to see what it actually checks against.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `GOTO` like that, as soon as `GOTO` is run the loop has broken, *(it does not return to the `FOR` loop)*. You could use `CALL` instead.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "user=username1"
SET "list=username3 username2 username1"

FOR %%A IN (%list%) DO IF /I "%user%"=="%%a" (CALL :MATCH1) ELSE CALL :MATCH2
PAUSE
EXIT/B

:MATCH1
notepad.exe
GOTO :EOF

:MATCH2
ECHO no
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I'd use `Echo no %1` and pass the current user `ELSE CALL :MATCH2 %%a`  otherwise you'd never know .... +1

Comment: @LotPings, I'm assuming that the OP isn't really opening `notepad.exe` as that serves no realistic purpose, likewise upon failed matches. For that reason I saw no need to change those things, because doing so would likely not affect the 'real' commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

set user=username1
set list=username3 username2 username1 

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO if %user%==%%a GOTO MATCH1 
GOTO MATCH2 

:MATCH1
notepad.exe

:MATCH2
echo no
```

You misunderstood `for`. `%%a` *would* acquire each of the list values in turn, and perform the match.

Either the match will be true or it will be false. No other choices. Your code checks for a match on the first string. On a match, goto `match1`. Otherwise, goto `match2`. This means you leave the loop, so the `for` only uses the first value.

with the modified code, the `goto` will be executed if the first string matches, otherwise it will look a the second, and otherwise at the third. If none match, the `for` has run out of options, so it terminates and executes the following instruction, which is `goto match2`.

Note that batch simply executes lines one by one until it reaches a `goto` `call` or `exit`. Consequently, once the instructions in `match1` are executed, execution will `flow through` to  the following instruction, so execute `match2` as well.